# How can I use Scrapy to download all my Quora answers?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, quora

I'm trying to use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) to download my Quora answers, but I can't even seem to be able to download my page. Using the simple

```
scrapy shell 'http://it.quora.com/profile/Ferdinando-Randisi'
```

returns this error

```
2017-10-05 22:16:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: quora)
2017-10-05 22:16:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quora.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': \[quora.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'quora', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
....
2017-10-05 22:16:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-10-05 22:16:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-10-05 22:16:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-10-05 22:16:54 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://it.quora.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://it.quora.com/robots.txt>
2017-10-05 22:16:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET https://it.quora.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-10-05 22:16:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://it.quora.com/profile/Ferdinando-Randisi> from <GET http://it.quora.com/profile/Ferdinando-Randisi>
2017-10-05 22:16:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET https://it.quora.com/profile/Ferdinando-Randisi> (referer: None)
2017-10-05 22:16:58 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
```

What's wrong? Error 429 is associated with too many requests, but I'm making only *one* request. Why would that be too many?

Comment: Read their [`robots.txt`](https://www.quora.com/robots.txt).

Comment: I did, but didn't see anything too relevant - they only write about how you should let them know if you use a search engine and they explain why they wouldn't like people download everybody's content. I'm doing neither of those things, I just want my answers.

Comment: Try with `curl` to see what happens.

Comment: What is curl? How do I use it? I'm sorry, I just started scraping and all of this is very new to me, I don't know much about it.

Comment: It would be lovely if people that downvoted provided some feedback about what they don't like, so that I can improve nex time.

Comment: Asking lazy questions like "What is curl?" is how you get down-voted. The answer is literally a search away, and as a bonus you only need to type in *four letters*. If you don't know what curl is, you can always find out. If you can demonstrate you've applied effort to solve your problem you'll get more help. If you throw up your hands at the first tiny obstacle it's going to look bad.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's very useful as I would have never guessed that someone could downvote an answer because of a genuine question in a comment, especially if there are at least four different tools that share the same name of the suggested tool, all coming up in the first google page result.

Comment: The results I see are the official cURL page, the how-to page, the PHP module that wraps the same library, and a GitHub project for the cURL source. I also get ads for curling irons which are clearly not related. I'm not sure if you're getting something wildly different, but if you are, that's very odd.

Comment: Very odd indeed! I do see those pages, but I also see the curl programming language, the curl web browser for R, the curl payment system, the curl command in Wolfram Alpha. It seems that google's search results are more varied than what one would assume. In hindsight curl wasn't actually very relevant to the problem anyway, since it's a separate tool and my question was about scrapy. However thanks much for being willing to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It blocks Scrapy based on user agent string. Try to mimic e.g. Chromium:

```
scrapy shell "http://it.quora.com/profile/Ferdinando-Randisi" -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"
```